# Get access token for Sign In with Apple targeting iOS 13 and above

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, apple-sign-in

This question is moreover related to Apple Sign In with iOS 13 and above, and to get access_token and refresh_token at the end of authorization.

I am developing a Sign In with Apple feature in Xamarin.Forms. I got sample code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/sign-in-with-apple/android-ios-sign-in).

For iOS 13:

- I used ASAuthorizationAppleIdButton, ASAuthorizationAppleIdProvider, ASAuthorizationAppleIdCredential etc to get id_token and authorization code.
- When I try to call validate token as mentioned over [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens) using my API support, apple throws 400 invalid_request (uses more than one mechanism for authenticating the client)
  I just wanted to know, how to get access_token, refresh_token in 2nd step for iOS 13 and above.

For non-iOS 13 (below iOS 13 and Android)

- We have implemented authorize and validate token endpoints on Api side with a callback URL
- I call my API endpoint in browser which ultimately calls apple [authorize](https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize) endpoint, once user completes the process, apple calls back redirect URL and there we exchange token or [validate token](https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token) using received authorization_code and state. At this step I receive access_token and refresh_token as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/tokenresponse).

I just wanted to know how to get access_token and refresh_token for iOS 13 like we are able to do it for non-iOS 13 platforms. 
Is it really needed to get access_token, refresh_token?

Thanking you in advance.

Update:

Server Auth API Call:
https://github.com/Redth/Xamarin.AppleSignIn.Sample/blob/master/AppleSignInAzureFunction/AppleSignInAuth.cs

Server Callback function:
https://github.com/Redth/Xamarin.AppleSignIn.Sample/blob/master/AppleSignInAzureFunction/AppleSignInCallback.cs

Server API implementation:
https://github.com/Redth/Xamarin.AppleSignIn.Sample/blob/master/Xamarin.AppleSignIn/AppleSignInClient.cs

Code Snippet:

```
public virtual Uri GenerateAuthorizationUrl()
{
   var respType = "code";

   var p = new Dictionary<string, string>
   {
       { "response_type", respType },
       { "response_mode", "form_post" },
       { "client_id", ServerId },
       { "redirect_uri", RedirectUri.OriginalString },
       { "nonce", Nonce },
       { "state", State },
       { "scope", "name email" }
   };
}

public async Task<AppleAccount> ExchangeTokenAsync(string code)
{
   var secret = GenerateClientSecretJWT(P8FileContents);

   var resp = await client.PostAsync(AppleTokenUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
   {
       { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
       { "code", code },
       { "redirect_uri", RedirectUri.OriginalString },
       { "client_id", ServerId },
       { "client_secret", secret },
   }));

   resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Comment: How does your API request looks like? what parameters you used?

Comment: I have updated the code for API requests and reference example which is followed for APIs.

Comment: Whats your value for ServerId in ExchangeTokenAsync ? If the authorization code comes from iOS, the client_id needs to be the bundle identifier of the iOS app, not services ID

Comment: API team tried with both Service Id and App Id (bundle identifier of the iOS app) but getting error code 400.

Comment: Hmmm, try removing redirect_uri parameter from the request , and use bundle identifier for client_id